# Wireless security get deleted every time

Tags: wireless-networking, security

I am using BSNL broadband connection with Huwai WA1003A modem cum router. I go to the router IP and set up wireless security like

1) MAC filter - Enabling Access list

2) WPA Security

But the next time I connect my computer, I find all the wireless security stuff is removed. The network becomes unsecured once again.

What is the reason for this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the setting I have to select option "save all setting" which is under a separate tab. Sorry I missed to notice that.